# Salvar equação digitada pelo usuário em python

Tags: python

Como eu poderia salvar uma equação matemática digitada pelo usuário e depois substituir valores nesta equação?

EX:
Usuário digitou: "3*x+2"
depois o programa substitui "x" por 1, mostrando ao final o valor 5 (3*1+2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe uma biblioteca em Python voltada para álgebra, o nome é [SymPy](http://scipy-lectures.org/advanced/sympy.html). É bem simples de usar, nesse exemplo aí, ficaria:

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
expr = expand(input())
num = int(input())
res = expr.subs(x, num)
print(res)
```

Para instalar o sympy basta usar o comando pip3 install sympy

Comment: Ele quer que saia o resultado da equação, seu programa faz isso?

Comment: Sim, o usuário digita a expressão numa linha e na outra digita o valor da variável x. Veja o link da documentação do Sympy para mais informações, você pode definir mais variáveis, se for o caso.

Comment: entendi, boa solução!

Comment: Muito obrigado Lorenzo, eu estava usando o Symbol() no lugar de expand() para salvar a equação digitada pelo usuário e não estava funcionando. O seu código funcionou perfeitamente!